# Post the id in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

I am working on PHP to display a modal when I click on a hyperlink. I have got a problem with post the ID in ajax, because it will not fetch the id from the hyperlink to post it in ajax so I don't know why.

I have tried this but it didnt work:

```
var id = $(this).attr('autoid');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "sendtest.php",
    data: {autoid : id},

    success: function(resultData)
    {
        alert(resultData)
    }
```

here is the code:

```
<span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="/delete_id.php?id=<?php echo $autoid ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>

<div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 12%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="height: 250px;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Send A Test Email</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 65%;">
               <form action="" method="post">
                    <label class="label-control" value="">Send test message to email address:</label>
                    <?php
                        $html = '<select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 18px; margin-left: 60px;">';
                        $values = array('unknown', $_SESSION["email"]);

                        foreach($values as $v)
                        {
                            $selected = '';
                            if($v == 'unknown')
                            {
                                $title = '';
                            }else{
                                $title = $v;
                            }

                            if($v == $_SESSION["from"])
                            {
                                $selected = "selected";
                            }
                            $html .= "<option $selected value='$v'>$title</option>";
                        }
                        $html .= "
                        </select><br>";
                        echo $html;
                    ?>

                    <button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;">Send Test</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$('#send_email').click(function(){
    document.getElementById("send_email").innerHTML = "<span><i class=\'fa fa-spinner fa-spin\'></i> Sending...</span>";
    document.getElementById('send_email').disabled = true;
    var id = $(this).attr('autoid');
    alert( $(this).attr('autoid'));


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "sendtest.php",
        data: {autoid : id},

        success: function(resultData)
        {
            alert(resultData)
            $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById("send_email").innerHTML = "Send Test";
            document.getElementById('send_email').disabled = false;
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

in sendtest.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;

}
else if(isset($_POST))
{
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $param_campaign = $_SESSION['campaign'];
    $id = $_POST['autocampaign'];
    echo "hello your id is...";
    echo $id;
} 
?>
```

I'm sorry if it have been posted very similar in the past, but this is a difficult situation I have been going through so I would like to get some help with this.

So what I am trying to do is when I click on a button to display on a modal and select a value, I click on a button again to get the ID `autoid` to post it via ajax and display the alert with the ID.

Can you please show me an example what is the correct way I could use to fetch the ID from the HTML tag called `autoid` so I can post it in ajax to display the ID in the alert?

Thank you.

**EDIT: It didn't work when I try this:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="/delete_id.php?id=<?php echo $autoid ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>
</form>
```

in sendtest.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;

}
else if(isset($_POST))
{
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $param_campaign = $_SESSION['campaign'];
    $id = $_POST['autoid'];
    echo "hello your id is...";
    echo $id;
}
?>
```

At all I get is `hello your id is...` in the alert.

**UPDATE: Here is the full code:**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mydbusername', 'mydbpassword', 'mydbname');
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $autocampaign = $_SESSION["campaign"];
    $auto_sql = "SELECT id, subject, day_cycle, enabled, delaysend FROM autore WHERE campaign ='$autocampaign' AND username ='$param_username'";

        $results = mysqli_query($link, $auto_sql);

         if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) 
         { 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $autoid = $row["id"];
                $autosubject = $row["subject"];
                $autodaycycle = $row["day_cycle"];
                $autoenabled = $row["enabled"];
                $autodelay = $row["delaysend"];
            }
         }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<style type="text/css">


.calendar-content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 112px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
}


</style>

<div class="calendar-content">
  <div style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 20px; height: 40px;">
    <span id="autosubject" style="font-size: 25px;color: #0c7ac0;float: left;">Subject: <?php echo $autosubject ?> </span><br>
    <div style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 15px; height: 40px;">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="deleteid" id="deleteid" href="/delete_id.php?id=<?php echo $autoid; ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <!-- email Modal -->
  <div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 12%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="height: 250px;">
        <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Send A Test Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 65%;">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label class="label-control" value="">Send test message to email address:</label>
            <select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 18px; margin-left: 60px;">
              <option selected="selected" value='title'>Title</option>";
            </select><br>
            <button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>">Send Test</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('#send_email').click(function(e) {
    $(this)
      .html("<span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending...</span>")
      .prop("disabled", true);
    var id = $(this).data('deleteid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "sendtest.php",
      data: {
        deleteid: id
      },
      success: function(resultData) {
        alert(resultData)
        $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
        $("#send_email")
          .html("Send Test")
          .prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're sending the `id` via `autoid` in the Post data, then in PHP you need to call it using that index: `$_POST['autoid']`. You're calling: `$id = $_POST['autocampaign'];` and that's not going to work.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you, so do I need to use `$_POST['autoid']` in ajax or in sendtest.php?

Comment: You will want to use `$_POST['autoid']` in `sendtest.php` when you want to access that Posted data.

Comment: The other problem is that your send email button doesn't have an attribute called autoid.

Comment: @RobertJones `var id = $(this).attr('autoid');` will fail since `$(this)` is a refernce to the Button Object and not the form. The `<button>` also does not have an attribute called `autoid`. Therefore, `id` will be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Twisty oh right, so do I need to change from `send_email` to `autoid` in the button? I want to fetch the id from the hyperlink.

Comment: `?id` is a GET request, not POST. Plus, what's the value of `$autoid`? and where and how is it set?

Comment: @RobertJones it's possible your SQL Query is returning more than 1 result or no result for `id`. What do you see in the resulting HTML for the Delete link? `?id=` what?

Comment: I see a few errors in your (full) code. I'd start by enabling error reporting and error handling on the mysql part too. I posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891733/post-the-id-in-ajax#comment94630816_53891733) earlier but didn't get a response. I only saw the edit because I still had this tabbed question open in my browser, which I might add won't be keeping it open after I posted this comment. So, debug your code with all methods, this including looking at your developer console; good luck. Btw, I added a few tags which I found to be relevant.

Comment: 2 more debugging tools: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and viewing your HTML source. Yes, the latter is also a (debugging) "tool". Btw, (Lord as my witness) can't say I didn't (try to) help. Debugging isn't our job, it's yours; so please remember that and it is an essential part of being a (learning) coder. Once you've figured that out, you'll see how relatively easy it will be for you to fix your own code later on. I only came back here because @Twisty replied to my comment under their answer, I'd of liked to have received the same courtesy from you Robert.

Answer (score 2):

In your `sendtest.php` you will want to change:

```
$id = $_POST['autocampaign'];
```

To the following:

```
$id = $_POST['autoid'];
```

Hope that helps.

**Updated**

`var id = $(this).attr('autoid');` will fail since `$(this)` is a refernce to the Button Object and not the form. The `<button>` also does not have an attribute called `autoid`. Therefore, `id` will be `null` or `undefined`.

Where should `id` get it's value from?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#send_email').click(function(e) {
    $(this)
      .html("<span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending...</span>")
      .prop("disabled", true);
    var id = $(this).data('auto-id');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "sendtest.php",
      data: {
        autoid: id
      },
      success: function(resultData) {
        alert(resultData)
        $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
        $("#send_email")
          .html("Send Test")
          .prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-content">
  <div style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 20px; height: 40px;">
    <span id="autosubject" style="font-size: 25px;color: #0c7ac0;float: left;">Subject: <?php echo $autosubject ?> </span><br>
    <div style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 15px; height: 40px;">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="/autoresponder/delete_autoresponder.php?id=<?php echo $autoid; ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <!-- email Modal -->
  <div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 12%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="height: 250px;">
        <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Send A Test Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 65%;">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label class="label-control" value="">Send test message to email address:</label>
            <select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 18px; margin-left: 60px;">
              <option selected="selected" value='title'>Title</option>";
            </select><br>
            <button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>">Send Test</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The following code is cleaned up. First, I added the `data-auto-id` attribute that contains the `autoid` from PHP. This can then be read and passed into the AJAX.

Also switched into all jQuery for consistency.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185637/discussion-on-answer-by-twisty-post-the-id-in-ajax).